# How do I create a 10x10 grid for polygons<1 kilometer in turf.js?

Tags: turfjs

How do I create a 10x10 grid for polygons<1 kilometer in turf.js?

```
let gridOptions = {units: 'kilometers'};

let grid = turf.squareGrid([ 176.4218616, -37.8028137, 176.4288378, -37.7992033 ], 100, gridOptions);
```

This produces an empty result. I presume because the polygon is too small.

Answer (score 1):

The units are applied to the `cellSide` argument when calling `squareGrid`. In your example your `cellSide` value is `100` meaning a grid with cells of size 100km². Change this value to resize the cells:

```
let grid = turf.squareGrid(bbox, 0.1, { units: 'kilometers'})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right: your area is less than 1sqkm:

```
const area_in_sqkm = turf.convertArea(
    turf.area(
        turf.bboxPolygon([176.4218616, -37.8028137, 176.4288378, -37.7992033])
    ),
    'meters', 'kilometers'
)

// area_in_sqkm = 0.2466
```